raylib + cURLpp == C2733 you cannot overload a function with 'extern "C" '
I tried making a weather app using cURL for the api request and raylib for the gui and both libraries worked until I combined them.
I thought that there is a mistake in my project configuration so I made a separate project where I only included raylib and cURL/cURLpp without any other code:
#include "raylib.h"
#include "curlpp/cURLpp.hpp"


int main()
{

}

and when I try to compile, I get this output:
Build started at 6:43 PM...
1>------ Build started: Project: weatherCpp, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>weatherCpp.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winuser.h(4710,1): error C2733: 'CloseWindow': you cannot overload a function with 'extern "C"' linkage
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winuser.h(9328,1): error C2733: 'ShowCursor': you cannot overload a function with 'extern "C"' linkage
1>Done building project "weatherCpp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 6:43 PM and took 02.010 seconds ==========

I looked around and I know it's because of functions declared with extern "C" but I dont know what to do about it is there an easy way of fixing this or do I need to switch libraries
*both libraries were downloaded with vcpkg 
**using vs 2022

FIXED:
I separated the visual studio solution into 2 projects, one was used for cURL (static library) and the other for raylib (.exe). I also put all the cURL code inside a namespace and now I don't get any errors and can create a window with raylib and do https requests with cURL no problem
This video helped me out
*Thanks for all the help btw :)

The problem is that both raylib.h and winuser.h contain functions CloseWindow() and ShowCursor() but with different parameters (because of they are totally different unrelated functions).
raylib.h

void CloseWindow(void);    

But:
winuser.h

BOOL CloseWindow(
  [in] HWND hWnd
);

You need to check where in your soucre file winuser.h is included (maybe from curl headers?)

Sidenote, just to give another starting point for research for the asker: you might be able to get rid of the conflicts by defining some macros.

@Oleg I tried to do what you said: to find where in my source file winuser.h was included from. I did that by using findstr /s /i /m \<"WinUser.h"\> *.*  from the folder where the vcpkg libraries are located at, and it seems like winuser.h can be found in a lot  of files related to libcurl so i might try using something else instead of cURLpp/cURL or maybe I will try separating the gui and http request sides of the app somehow (not sure how tho, maybe multiple projects inside a single solution? Idk if that would help)

@user25257007 I downloaded https://github.com/datacratic/curlpp and didn't see any inclusion of winuser.h. You should find what else causes its inclusion. Maybe there are other includes that may include winuser.h.
You can also run "preprocess only" C++ compiler command on your file "CL /P /C weatherCpp.cpp" and then you can see in the output where winuser.h is included from

Raylib is a compatibility mess in relation to Windows - not only risks UB but also maintainer offers solutions for workaround which may end  badly. There are some user-offered workarounds https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/issues/1217 libcurl uses windows.h on Windows platform, under the hood.
